# Calculate the current balance in Query to add/subtract based on the transaction type?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my query :

```
SELECT track_no,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN credit_type IS NOT NULL
    THEN credit_type
    ELSE debit_type
  END) AS transaction_type,
  (
  CASE WHEN credit_type IS NOT NULL
  then credit_units else
  debit_units end
  ) as units,
  track_dt,
  (select prv_free_units from benf_ewr_track where track_dt='28-JUN-17 04.51.17.291000000 PM')  as openingbalance
FROM benf_ewr_track where track_dt BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2017/06/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Result :

[image]

I have 3 cases to add /subtract the values.

1. Opening balance should be the previous date closing balance.
2. Add the opening balance with units of specific row,when the transaction_Type is credit.
3. Subtract the added value with units of specific row, when the transaction_type is debit.

**Note: This calculation needs to be calculated in query.**

**Expected Result ::**
[image]

**Example case :**

Here,The closing balance of previous date(27-JUN-17 05.09.48.204000000 PM
) is 1500. 
Next day(28-JUN-17 05.09.48.204000000 PM),
The credit units is 20 and it added up with previous closing balance. So,opening balance is 1520. 
Then followed by debit, subtracted with 15 gives 1505.

Any answers and suggestions will be appreciated ?
Thanks,

Comment: Why downvote ?Give me Suggestion so that  I can improve my way of asking the questions

Comment: Since you ask add sample data as text to the question (or to sqlfiddle),cut down the amount of data to an absolute minimum that illustrates your problem and ensure the sample data and your query have matching names.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (I doubt that query runs on both products.)

Comment: Tip of today: `COALESCE(credit_type, debit_type) as transaction_type`.

Comment: @jarlh,oracle. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Thanks. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SUM( ... ) OVER ( ORDER BY ... )` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT track_no,
         COALESCE( credit_type,   debit_type  ) AS transaction_type,
         COALESCE( credit_units, -debit_units ) as units,
         track_dt,
         SUM( COALESCE( credit_units, 0 ) - COALESCE( debit_units, 0 ) )
           OVER ( ORDER BY track_dt )
           AS Balance
  FROM   benf_ewr_track
)
WHERE  track_dt BETWEEN DATE '2017-06-28' AND SYSDATE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But,it isn't working on my case. Just have a look into my case. Need to add the value on credit and subtract on debit.